# General Topology (Willard) Exercise 18H about topological manifolds

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds

I have some difficulties with this Exercise: let X be a compact Hausdorff locally euclidean space of dimension m, U an open subset of X such that U Is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and ~ the equivalence relation on X that identifies $X-U$ to a single point; prove that X/~ is homeomorphic to $S^m$.

MY IDEA: Let $g: U\to\mathbb{R}^m$ a homeomorphism e let $f:= p\circ g\colon U\to S^m-\{N\}$ where
$p\colon \mathbb{R}^m\to S^m-\{N\}$ is the inverse of the stereographic projection from the north pole $N$ of the $m$-sphere $S^m$. Now, I define $F\colon X/$~ $\to S^m$ in this way
$
F([x])= f(x)$ for $x\in U$ and $F([x])=N$ for $x\in X-U$. Clearly $F$ is bijective. If I will prove that $F$ is continuous I'de finish, why? Because $X/$~ is compact (since it's the quotient of the compact space X) and $S^m$ is a Hausdorff space, so every continous function from $X/$~ to $S^m$ is a closed map, and then a homeomorphism if it is also bijective (likewise it is my $F$). So, can anyone help me in order to prove that the continuity of $F$?

Comment: Is some condition missing? This looks false in general. Consider $X = (0, 1)$ and $U = (0, \frac{1}{2})$. Then $X/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $(0, 1]$ which I think is not homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: In addition, while $M$ has many open sets which are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, it also has many which are not.  But it looks like you're assuming $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I forgot an hypotesis, U Is omeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and X Is compact! Sorry!

Comment: Now I've just corrected my question, now there are all the hypothesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$\phi : X \to S^m, \phi(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \in U \\ N & x \in X \setminus U \end{cases}$$
Then clearly $\phi$ is continuous in all points of $U$.

Now let $x \in X \setminus U$ and $V$ be an open neighborhood of $\phi(x) = N$ in $S^m$. The set $K = S^m \setminus V$ is a closed subset of $S^m$, thus it is compact and contained in $S^m \setminus \{ N \}$. Hence $f^{-1}(K)$ is a compact subset of $U$. Because $X$ is Hausdorff, $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed in $X$ and $W = X \setminus f^{-1}(K)$ is open in $X$ . By construction $x \in  X \setminus U \subset W$ and $\phi(W) \subset V$. To verify this inclusion, note that $W \cap U =  U \setminus f^{-1}(K)$ so that $\phi(W \cap U) = f(W \cap U) = f(U) \setminus K = (S^m \setminus \{ N \}) \setminus (S^m \setminus V) = V \setminus \{N \}$.

Thus $\phi$ is continuous. We have $F \circ q = \phi$, where $q : X \to X/$~ is the quotient map. The universal property of the quotient shows then that $F$ is continuous.

Note that the above argument only requires that $X$ is Hausdorff. The compactness of $X$ is used to show that $F$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much. A question: so we don't need the hypothesis "X is locally euclidean of dimension $m$" to prove the assertion?

Comment: @JohnMax6 No, it suffices to know that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Just a question: $\phi(W)=V$ ? Look: since $W=X-f^{-1}(K)=(X-U)\cup (U-f^{-1}(K))$, we have that $\phi(W)=\{N\}\cup f(U-f^{-1}(K))=\{N\}\cup [(S^m-\{N\})-K]=\{N\}\cup [(S^m-\{N\})-(S^m-J)]=\{N\}\cup [J-\{N\}]=J$. @PaulFrost what do you think?

Comment: @JohnMax6 Yes, this is correct.